# for loop - print values in order - PHP

Tags: php, for-loop

I need to print the below statement.

> Thanks for updating your PH_NUMBER, ADDRESS, OFFICE NUMBER and EMAIL.

Where `PH_NUMBER, ADDRESS, OFFICE_NUMBER and EMAIL` are variables.

For example, if value is empty for variable `"OFFICE_NUMBER"` the sentence should be like below:

> Thanks for updating your PH_NUMBER, ADDRESS and EMAIL.

For example, if value is empty for variable `"EMAIL"` the sentence should be like below:

> Thanks for updating your PH_NUMBER, ADDRESS and OFFICE NUMBER.

```
$a = "Address";
$b = "Mobile";
$c = "email";

$array = array($a, $b, $c);

$length = count($array);

for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++) {
  $total = $array[$i];
}

echo "Thanks for udpating " . $total ;
```

How can this be done ?
Any suggestions would be helpful.

Comment: Show us what you have tried so far **SO is not a free coding service**

Comment: Have you tried writing it yourself?

Comment: Please read [What topics can I ask about](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)
and [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
And [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/)
And how to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: I don't have access to copy the code from my dev machine. That's the reason I can't able to add here...

Comment: It Can Be Done In Many Ways. But, Question Is What Have You Tried?

Comment: Oh.. At least Type Here. For printing this, it will not take more than 3-4 lines.

Comment: I've tried using the for loop. Based on the condition the values will print. But, it is not working as expected..

Comment: @NanaPartykar: Done.. give me couple of minutes to edit the question.'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to use a loop.

```
<?php
    /* Collect all parameters to the array */
    $variables = [
        'PH_NUMBER',
        'ADDRESS',
        'EMAIL',
        'OFFICE_NUMBER',
    ];
    /* Sorting the array if need */
    /* Pop the element off the end of array */
    $variables = array_filter($variables);
    $count = count($variables);
    $lastVariable = array_pop($variables);

    if($count > 1) {
        printf('Thanks for updating your %s and %s', implode(', ', $variables), $lastVariable);
    }elseif($count === 1){
        printf('Thanks for updating your %s', $lastVariable);
    }else{
        print 'Nothing for update';
    }
?>
```

**Update:** Small improvement in order to catch cases with only 1 variable and empty array (nothing for update).

Comment: Good solution, just put `$variables = array_filter($variables);` before `array_pop()` in order to remove/filter all empty variables as OP requests.

Comment: thanks for your input.. But, some times the values may be empty. In that case, the sentence will not be proper. For example, if the last variable "OFFICE_NUMBER" is empty the the sentence will be like "'Thanks for updating your PH_NUMBER, ADDRESS, EMAIL and ". Which is wrong.

Comment: @Fero, see my comment.

Comment: Thanks.. it work like a charm.. :-)